# cannot place radio buttons vertically middle

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapt{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
background:gold;
}
.inplus{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 width:50px;
 margin-right:7px;
}
.radiowhat{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.labelwhat{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapt'>
<div class='wrapta'>
<input type='text' class='inplus' id='inplus' autocomplete = 'off' placeholder = '+'>
<input type='radio' class='radiowhat'><label for='radiofolder' class='labelwhat'>folder</label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='radio' class='radiowhat'><label for='radiofile' class = 'labelwhat'>file</label>
</div>
<div class='wraptb'></div>
</div>
```

Why are the radio buttons not vertically centred?

Comment: The user agent (browser) applies margins to the radio button. Add the following to .radiowhat: margin: 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to add `margin: 0px` to the `.radiowhat` class.

```
.radiowhat {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Chrome and Firefox useragents automatically add margins to radio inputs, so resetting them will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try not using a `<div>` element around everything, and do this:

```
<input type='text' class='inplus' id='inplus' autocomplete = 'off' placeholder = '+'>
<input type='radio' class='radiowhat'><label for='radiofolder' class='labelwhat'>folder</label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='radio' class='radiowhat'><label for='radiofile' class = 'labelwhat'>file</label>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.radiowhat {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

This will both centre your radio buttons and make it responsive.

Comment: but, of course I need a parent, i.e. a div arround.

Comment: So make the `<div>` a full page, with `height: 100%; width: 100%`

Comment: no, my page design is not a full page and the radios inside. It's a grid, just as I wrote.